# JavaFX drag button from one pane to another

Tags: button, javafx, drag-and-drop

I have a javafx application that contains a number of buttons inside a single flowpane. To make the buttons draggable, I have put each button inside an individual pane. The user can pick any button from any one pane and drag & drop it on any other pane. E.g., get the button from pane 1 and drag it over and drop it inside pane 5.

Since it is previously unknown which button the user will pick, I assume it has to be added somehow to the a dragboard first, so it can be retrieved from the dragboard on the setOnDragDropped operation.

I am able to drag and drop images between imageviews by using:

```
    Dragboard db = iv_1.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.MOVE);
    ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
    content.putImage(iv_1.getImage());
```

But I can't figure out a way to add a button to a dragboard, since the are no specific options available, only options that do not seem to apply, content.putText, or content.putString() ...

Any help would be appreciated. This is what I have so far:

```
private void btn_1_setOnDragDetected(MouseEvent event) {

    Dragboard db = btn_1.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.MOVE);
    ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
    // below seems to be wrong
    content.put(dataFormat,btn_1.toString());
    db.setContent(content);

    event.consume();
}


private void btn_1_setOnDragOver(DragEvent event) {

    if (event.getGestureSource() != btn_1 &&
            event.getDragboard().hasString()) {
        event.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.MOVE);
    }
    event.consume();
}


private void pane_5_setOnDragDropped(DragEvent event) {

    Dragboard db = event.getDragboard();
    boolean success = false;
    if (db.hasString()) {
       // below must be wrong
       pane_5.setId(db.getString());
       success = true;
    }
    event.setDropCompleted(success);
    event.consume();
    }
```

Comment: Just throwing out ideas.  Could you copy the buttons important details and create a new button on drag release at that location. Then used the detail to determine the button functionality?

Comment: `setId` doesn't add the button to the pane. Look at the java [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#getId--).

Comment: [`startFullDrag`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#startFullDrag--) + use [`MouseDragEvent.getGestureSource`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/MouseDragEvent.html#getGestureSource--). And btw dump the idea with the `Dragboard`. Dragging the `Button` somewhere outside your application doesn't make sense, but `Dragboard` is used for dragging data independent of the source app...

Comment: Guys, many thanks for your contributions .....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to add a button to the clipboard content (i.e. to the dragboard). You can only add specific types (string, image) and objects that implement serializable (button doesn't, and it wouldn't do what you wanted anyway). The drag-and-drop API is very deficient in this aspect, imho. You should just add some dummy text to the dragboard and keep a reference to the button that is currently being dragged.

Quick SSCCE:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Orientation;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.SplitPane;
import javafx.scene.input.ClipboardContent;
import javafx.scene.input.DataFormat;
import javafx.scene.input.Dragboard;
import javafx.scene.input.TransferMode;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class DragAndDropButton extends Application {

    private final DataFormat buttonFormat = new DataFormat("com.example.myapp.formats.button");

    private Button draggingButton ;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        FlowPane pane1 = new FlowPane();
        FlowPane pane2 = new FlowPane();

        for (int i = 1 ; i <= 10; i++) {
            pane1.getChildren().add(createButton("Button "+i));
        }

        addDropHandling(pane1);
        addDropHandling(pane2);

        SplitPane splitPane = new SplitPane(pane1, pane2);
        splitPane.setOrientation(Orientation.VERTICAL);

        Scene scene = new Scene(splitPane, 600, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private Button createButton(String text) {
        Button button = new Button(text);
        button.setOnDragDetected(e -> {
            Dragboard db = button.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.MOVE);
            db.setDragView(button.snapshot(null, null));
            ClipboardContent cc = new ClipboardContent();
            cc.put(buttonFormat, "button");
            db.setContent(cc);
            draggingButton = button ;
        });
        button.setOnDragDone(e -> draggingButton = null);
        return button ;
    }

    private void addDropHandling(Pane pane) {
        pane.setOnDragOver(e -> {
            Dragboard db = e.getDragboard();
            if (db.hasContent(buttonFormat) 
                    && draggingButton != null 
                    && draggingButton.getParent() != pane) {
                e.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.MOVE);
            }
        });

        pane.setOnDragDropped(e -> {
            Dragboard db = e.getDragboard();
            if (db.hasContent(buttonFormat)) {
                ((Pane)draggingButton.getParent()).getChildren().remove(draggingButton);
                pane.getChildren().add(draggingButton);
                e.setDropCompleted(true);
            }           
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```